# How can I know if the Firebase is the first login? Data exists?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This is Firebase Anonymous Login Code.

I want to know how to code `if(????)`

When I read the data, I thought it would be null if there was no data.

`DBreference.Child("UserData").Child(fireUser .UserId).GetValueAsync()`

This code is not null

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
DBreference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
User userData = null; // User class include userdata

auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
{
 fireUser = task.Result;
 //Always automatically login success

 //This part is read Data from Firebase.Database
 DBreference.Child("UserData").Child(fireUser.UserId).
 GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task2 => 
 {
     if(????) // data dosen't exist
     {
         userData = new User();
         string jsonString = JsonFx.Json.JsonWriter.Serialize(userData);
         DBreference.Child("UserData").Child(fireUser.UserId).
         SetRawJsonValueAsync(jsonString);
     }
     else // data exists
     { 
         jsonString = task2.Result.GetRawJsonValue();
         userData = JsonFx.Json.JsonReader.Deserialize<User>(jsonString);            
     }
 });
});
```

Comment: Do you want to know if there is or not data in the database after the user logged in??

If no data it means it is a new user and then u can create the user data, am i right?

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 0):

OK, after reading your comments I understand now what are you after
You need to swap if/else

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
DBreference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
{
 fireUser = task.Result;

 if(task.IsFaulted) // user doesn't exist
 { 
   userData = new User(); 
   string jsonString = JsonFx.Json.JsonWriter.Serialize(userData);
   DBreference.Child("UserData").Child(fireUser .UserId).           
   SetRawJsonValueAsync(jsonString);
 }
 else //user exists
 {
    DBreference.Child("UserData").Child(fireUser .UserId).
    GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task3 =>
    {
        jsonString = task3.Result.GetRawJsonValue();      
        userData = JsonFx.Json.JsonReader.Deserialize<User>(jsonString);
    });
 }
});
```

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: task.result always return DataSnapshot... data exists or not .  so task.isFaulted is always false

Comment: Are you sure? I though it will be true if wrong username or password

Comment: The problem there is you are checking the result of the sign in not the data read. Which one do you want?

Comment: No account, no data
So it creates account + data generation
If there is an account, it will read the data because it will be there

Comment: "auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync()" This is a function provided by FireBase.  If you do not have an account, automatically create it.
If you have an account, log in.
So we can not check this stage. So we save the title of the data as uid and read that the uid is matched. So I have to find that the title of the data is uid
If it reads,
If not, it will create

Comment: I'm sorry I did not speak English well.   To say it easily. if(FirebaseUser.uid is exsist in Firebase.Database 's title) ->  {read data}  else{ create data }

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: task is login part not database.   task2 is read database part.  that is my mistake swap comment. i fixed it

Comment: You are writing the user in both cases, this is also wrong. Updated the answer

Comment: Yes, I changed the answer

Comment: im very very sorry. Give me the last chance. I entered the missing code. im check logcat, task2 always return DataSnapshot if data exists or not. so task2.isFaulted is always false.

Comment: Is this also when putting new user details that don't exist?

Comment: Thank you very much. Your advice has helped me a lot. I found a way. if(????) -> if(!task2.Result.exists). It works fine.